# objective c post get request with body

Tags: objective-c, http-post

I have the server and encrypt:93mrLIMApU1lNM619WzZje4S9EeI4L2L.
I want to connect and get json from it. I tried:

```
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://mydomain.co.il/clubs"]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];


NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:[NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration]];
[[session dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
    NSString *requestReply = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"requestReply: %@", requestReply);
}] resume];
```

But I get: html source with "Invalid Encryption key". 
Somebody said me that without body I'll not get the result. What should I do? And what about encrypt:93mrLIMApU1lNM619WzZje4S9EeI4L2L ?

Answer (score 1):

Your encoding of the data might be wrong, try changing it to utf-8 encoding like this:

```
NSString *requestReply = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```